# when does isomorphism on fibers between scheme theoretic maps imply isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that a: Y --> Z is a map of schemes over a scheme X, and that a induces an isomorphism on the scheme theoretic fiber over each point of X. What are minimal hypotheses that guarantee that a is an isomorphism?

--David Eisenbud and Joe Harris

Comment: What do you mean by writing the two names at the end? Is this a question originally posed by them?

Comment: Whoever is responsible for these things, I would recommend you close this question unless the OP explains what he means by writing those names.  If this is a homework problem, it is more appropriate for stack exchange.

Comment: If this is a direct quote, it does not seem to be known to Google.